# How to create a bookmark for some section of page which is present on different website using href attribute in HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, bookmarks

Consider the scenario where I've one website having URL `http://www.abcd.com`. On this website suppose there is a file titled `index.html`. This `index.html` file contains HTML code.

Now I want to provide the user with a hyperlink on the page `index.html` which will redirect the user to the location present on some page say `about_us.html` on website `http://www.pqr.com`.

The section on the page `about_us.html` of website `http://www.pqr.com` has id="abt".

How should I show it?

Comment: What can you stop from using `about_us.html#abt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your ABC index.html page, add the following markup...

```
<a href="http://www.prq.com/about_us.html#abt">About PQR</a>
```

Further info on [how to create links to sections on the same page in HTML](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm).